# Keep div hide if already has been clicked Jquery - MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

have implement this [code](http://www.encodedna.com/jquery/create-a-facebook-like-notifications-using-jquery-css.htm) so to show notifications to the visitors.

My controller

```
     public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var notification = (from r in db.Notification
                            select r);

        ViewBag.NotifyTotal = notification.Count();

        return View(db.Notification.ToList());
    }
```

My view

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <div id="noti_Counter"></div>
                                <div id="noti_Button"></div>
                            </a>
```

My jquery

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#noti_Counter')
        .css({ opacity: 0 })
        .text('@ViewBag.NotifyTotal')            
        .css({ top: '-10px' })
        .animate({ top: '-2px', opacity: 1 }, 500);

    $('#noti_Button').click(function () {


        $('#notifications').fadeToggle('fast', 'linear', function () {
            if ($('#notifications').is(':hidden')) {
                $('#noti_Button').css('background-color', '#2E467C');
            }
            else $('#noti_Button').css('background-color', '#FFF');


        });

        $('#noti_Counter').fadeOut('slow');    


        return false;
    });


    $(document).click(function () {
        $('#notifications').hide();


        if ($('#noti_Counter').is(':hidden')) {


            $('#noti_Button').css('background-color', '#2E467C');

        }
    });

    $('#notifications').click(function () {

        return false;     
    });



});
</script>
```

I need to keep the noti_Counter hidden on refresh page if the user has already clicked once at the noti_button.

Do I have to do it through jquery or can I check it to my controller with a flag so to know if the user has clicked the notifications and turn the counter = 0?

thank you

Comment: you can use localstorage for that

Answer (score 1):

Use `localStorage`.

```
$('#noti_Button').click(function () {
    localStorage.setItem('hasViewed',"yes");
    //Other code
});
```

Then in `document.ready` access it as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var isViewed=localStorage.setItem('hasViewed');
   if(isViewed==="yes")
      $('#noti_Counter').hide();  //hope this line hides notification 
   //remaining code
});
```

You also need to take care if new notification appears. `localStorage` would not be good option in this case and I would go with **`server side razor generating syntax`** based on certain condition.

What you can do is, add an extra row to your `notification table` which would be `isSeen`. Once the user clicks on `notification`, send an ajax request and make the `isSeen` value for each row as `true` and then in your code while fetching `notification` fetch only those records where `isSeen` is `false`. Then based on the `count` of `notification`, `hide` or `show` the `notification` in razor syntax. This would help you fetch only `unseen` notification during each page refresh.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I dont want to hide the notifications div (is lets say the dropdown menu). Just the counter. I change your code to $('#noti_Counter').hide(); but on refresh it still brings the counter.

Comment: Can you `alert` or `console.log` what's the value you fetch from `isViewed` on `document.ready`?

Comment: is yes...I change the row and it works but it always hide the counter. I also notice that when I click on the noti_button it doesn't bring the dropdown menu.

Comment: That's why I mentioned a different approach at the end for dynamic notifications. This will hide `notifications` permanently.. Its better to decide what `html` to generate with `razor` in serverside itself..

Comment: Yes I suppose I have to use the flag isSeen so to bring the new notifications also. I will give a try and I will be back with the new code thank you

Comment: Hello Guruprasad Rao, I have made some changes in my code and database but it doesn't work. It will be great if you can help. You can see it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270348/on-div-click-set-checkbox-to-true-ajax-mvc-5. Thank you