# On div click set checkbox to true Ajax MVC 5

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to display notifications to users of my site. When the user clicks the notify button it should hide the counter. And display only notifications that the NotificationIsSeen is false

My model

```
    //other fields
    [Display(Name = "Viewed")]
    public bool NotificationIsSeen { get; set; }
```

My Controller **Edit**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
       var notification = (from r in db.Notification
                            where r.NotificationIsSeen == false
                            select r);
        ViewBag.NotificationIsSeen = false;
        ViewBag.NotifyTotal = notification.Count();
        return View();
    }
```

My view **Edit**

```
                            <!-- Menu toggle button -->
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" id="notify_button"></i>
                                 @if (ViewBag.NotifyTotal > 0)
                                {
                                    <span class="label label-success" id="notify_counter">@ViewBag.NotifyTotal</span>

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <span class="label label-success" id="notify_counter"></span>

                                }

                            </a>
```

My ajax code:

```
<script>
    $('#notify_button').click(function () {
        $('#notify_counter').fadeOut('slow');
        $.ajax({
            url: "@(Url.Action("Index", "Home"))",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                NotificationIsSeen: "True" //I am not sure if this is correct

            }
        });
   });
```

onclick the notify_button it hides the notify_counter, but it brings it again on refresh page.

Any idea?
thank you

Comment: Does your `ajax` request updates db?

Comment: If you want to display only notifications that have not been seen, then you query should have a `.Where(x => !NotificationIsSeen)` and you ajax call should be calling a controller method that sets that value to `false`

Comment: No it doesn't update the database.

Comment: I update my controller so to bring only the notification that is not seen. I cannot find the way to update my DB through the ajax. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the solution maybe is useful for someone.

My controller

```
public ActionResult IsSeen()

    {
        var query = from r in db.Notification
                    where r.NotificationIsSeen == false
                    select r;

        foreach (Notification r in query)
        {
            r.NotificationIsSeen = true;


            }

        db.SaveChanges();
        return View();

    }
```

My ajax

```
<script>
    $('#notify_button').click(function () {
        $('#notify_counter').fadeOut('slow');

        $.ajax({
            url: "@(Url.Action("IsSeen", "Home"))",


          });
   });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update "NotificationIsSeen" parameter in DB and then you have to get value from NotificationIsSeen's value from DB in your controller.